# custom htaccess rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a website and i want to change this url:

```
www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=someOption
```

to this:

```
www.mysite.com/search/service/someOption
```

In the file `service.php`, there is a list of options. i will be adding/removing options in the future, but i want it to always change `/service.php?option=whateverIsHere` to `service/whateverIsHere`

I don't know how to work with htaccess and whatever i put just wont work. i cant even change `www.mysite.com/search` to anything. I have tried tutorials and the only thing that managed to work was:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks <br>
Options +Indexes <br>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] <br>
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC] <br>
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

This removed the `.php` everywhere, but i don't want this... i want only `/search/service.php` to be affected.

Thanks for any help.

**edit:**

i have this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /service.php\?option=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/service/%1    [R,L,NC]
```

which makes me change this:

```
www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=someOption
```

to this:

```
www.mysite.com/search/service/someOption?option=someOption
```

so im almost there... I just need to get rid of the ?option=someOption at the end of that url...  anyone can help??

Comment: ok i have this:
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /service.php\?option=([^\s&]+) [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /search/service/%1    [R,L,NC]

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to PHP.
But you can use the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/search/service.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=([a-z0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /search/service/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule search/service/(.*?)$ /search/service.php?option=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tested the code. Make sure you are not using any other related rules that might be overriding it. So using this code when you visit search/service/your_service it will show service.php?option=your_service

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks  
 Options +Indexes
 RewriteEngine On


 RewriteRule search/service/(.*?)$ service.php?option=$1 [L]

Comment: I edited the code. Try now. (Added the search directory in the rewrite url) /search/service.php?option=$1

Comment: when i type www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical I see 404 page not found. when i type www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical

then i see the right page

Comment: ok now it works. i typed www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical and it showed the right page...

Comment: If it solved your problem then mark the answer as correct.

Comment: so it redirects from www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical to www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical

but now all I need is to rewrite www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical to www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical in the address bar...

Comment: kuz one is externally redirect the other is internal redirect.

what you sent i think would be internal redirect. i also need the external redirect...

Comment: It is not redirecting. It is rewrite. You said you want to rewrite from /service.php?option=whateverIsHere to service/whateverIsHere

Comment: yea but when I click on my form and fill out what service I want, it sends me to www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical

it still shows up as that in the address bar

Comment: but if i manually write in the address bar www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical it goes to www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical

Comment: which is good, since I want  www.mysite.com/search/service/electrical to goes to www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical but I also want www.mysite.com/search/service.php?option=electrical to never show up in the address bar if a link goes to there. you know?

Comment: almost got it... just need to get rid of the extra ?option=someOption

Comment: thats working, but the only problem is I just realized its affecting other php files on my website, redirecting them to service/myFILE.php?var=wtv...  its putting a /service in the url everywhere... is there a way to rid of that?

Comment: its still doing it. I have a link that goes to www.mysite.com/search/view_info.php?id=VAR&option=VAR2 and it becomes: www.mysite.com/search/service/view_info.php?id=VAR$option=VAR2

Comment: I tried but it is not giving me this problem. It will only redirect /search/service.php and rewrites search/service/, www.mysite.com/search/view_info.php?id=VAR has no /service/ directory so it should not happen.